# How to avoid showing duplicate values in an inner join

Tags: sql, select, duplicates

[image]I am trying not to show duplicate values in the ORDER column from the results list; however, I am showing duplicate "ORDER" values. How can I fix this?

```
        select i.contractnumber as "CONTRACT NUMBER", t.ordernumber as
        "ORDER", t.title as "ORDER TITLE", c.companyname as "COMPANY",
        LEFT(cs.firstname, 1) +'. '+ cs.lastname as "TECHINICAN",
        REPLACE(cs.CONTACT,'703-735-', 'x') as "CONTACT (703) 735....)"
        from Company c inner join CONTRACTS i
          on i.Company_ID = c.Company_ID
        inner join Orders t
          on t.ordernumberid = i.ordernumberid
        inner join hub rut
          on rut.titleOrder_ID = t.titleOrder_ID
        inner join hub2 r
          on r.Role_ID = rut.Role_ID
        inner join Customer u
          on u.Customer_ID = rut.Customer_ID
        inner join CORD cs
          on cs.CORD_ID = u.CORD_ID
        inner join Method cv
          on cv.Method_ID = i.Method_ID
        where cs.Contact LIKE '%703-735-%'
          and cv.Method_ID = 1;
```

[image]

Comment: It's a little hard to troubleshoot this without knowing some data (or even fake data that sort of resembles real data, if it's sensitive data you're working with) exists within these tables.  My best guess is that you're missing a condition in your where clause, or in one of the join clauses, however it's difficult to say exactly where.

Comment: I added an image so that you can see the data results. Thanks.

Comment: You're getting 3 records per order because there are 3 unique technicians and contact numbers... Can you also show us what your desired results are?

Comment: My desired result is to have unique values in the ORDER column. I do not want the ORDER column duplicated againstthe same CONTRACT NUMBER. If the other columns are duplicate, I will not care.

Comment: As mentioned by Aaron, you are getting 3 rows for order 0001 because there were 3 rows in the CORD table for that CORD_ID. You have a couple options, if you want to keep your WHERE condition of cs.Contact LIKE '%703-735-%' then you will need to add a group by clause, and group down to the uniq order, but that will require you to get rid of the Technicians name, If you want the technicians name(s) all in one row, you will need to concatenate them.

Comment: OMIT the middle image. I did not know how to delete it.

Comment: Another option would be to have a inner query for the CORD table that only returns at most 1 technician, but again it depends on your needs.

Comment: @caa35 -- I deleted that image for you.

Comment: @ JBdev, How could I do an inner query for the CORD? Is the inner query I currently have inadequate? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The simple way to fix this is with a group by -- eg `GROUP BY Order` however if you have more than one value for the other columns  you will have an issue -- you can pick a value -- for example max.  That would like like this:

```
select
  max(i.contractnumber) as "CONTRACT NUMBER", 
  t.ordernumber as "ORDER", 
  max(mat.title) as "ORDER TITLE", 
  max(c.companyname) as "COMPANY",
  max(LEFT(cs.firstname, 1) +'. '+ cs.lastname) as "TECHINICAN",
  max(REPLACE(cs.CONTACT,'703-735-', 'x')) as "CONTACT (703) 735....)"
-- etc as you have
-- ...
-- end with
GROUP BY t.ordernumber
```

Comment: Another way to approach this, if there legitimately ARE supposed to be multiple values would be to use something like MS SQL's `STUFF`, though we'd need to know the specifics of the db.

Comment: Thanks Hogan for your example. Your example is closer than where I was originally.